How do I ensure that my Frontend is the Origin sending a POST request to my Backend
I have a Vue 3 frontend site that I want to be able to sign up new users. When the user enters their information into the frontend, the frontend will send a POST request to the backend which is a Django REST API. The backend will then create the user.
But how can I verify that the frontend is the Origin sending the request? I would think there would be a problem if someone just set up a script to execute 1000 curl commands to flood my database with users (although I guess someone could still do this if they set up an automated script to enter information via selenium or something).
Would it be secure for Django to look at the Origin header when handling the POST request or can this be forged?
I have also already read the accepted answer here but it did not really answer my question.

Anything coming from the client side (Your frontend in this case) can be faked, that includes the Origin header and potentially various other techniques you might think of. If you want to protect an API authenticate the user. As to your concerns about the 1000 curl commands, etc. protecting the server from DOS and other attacks is the task of a firewall, not your application.

Note that you can implement some rate limits on your server potentially based on IP address.
